# Tooltip not working with JQuery 1.11.2

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am trying to show a tooltip over a label on move hover. I followed this [Tooltip tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-create-a-tooltips-with-jquery/) to get thet work. This tutorial uses JQuery 1.4.2 and my project is build on JQuery 1.11.2. The tooltip works on 1.4.2 but not on 1.11.2.

Is the support for tooltip is removed in JQuery ? Am I missing any ?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #hint{
                cursor:pointer;
            }
            .tooltip{
                margin:8px;
                padding:8px;
                border:1px solid blue;
                background-color:yellow;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 2;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>jQuery tooltips example</h1>
        <label id="username">Username : </label><input type="text" / size="50"> 
        <span id="authentication-password-tooltip">Password(?)</span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var changeTooltipPosition = function(event) {
                    var tooltipX = event.pageX - 8;
                    var tooltipY = event.pageY + 8;
                    $('div.tooltip').css({top: tooltipY, left: tooltipX});
                };
                var showTooltip = function(event) {
                    $('div.tooltip').remove();
                    $('<div class="tooltip">I\' am tooltips! tooltips! tooltips! :)</div>')
                        .appendTo('body');
                    changeTooltipPosition(event);
                };
                var hideTooltip = function() {
                    $('div.tooltip').remove();
                };
                $("span#authentication-password-tooltip,label#username'").bind({
                    mousemove : changeTooltipPosition,
                    mouseenter : showTooltip,
                    mouseleave: hideTooltip
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a typo in the last selector (an extra `'`) it should be: `$("span#authentication-password-tooltip,label#username")`. If you fix that it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/15sk4wks/

Comment: Also just FYI, whenever you get some JS code that doesn't work, the first thing to do is check the console for an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `'` from your `$("span#authentication-password-tooltip,label#username'")`; it's breaking the script.

[Here's a **working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s4ehahtg/)

Some general advice: as pointed out in the comments, you should always check the console first when you have a JavaScript error. Also, [1.4.2 is *very* old now](https://jquery.org/history/) (more than 5 years). A lot has changed, so you should try to look for more current tutorials in the future.

Comment: Glad to help! Please remember to select an answer! :)